# Add goal in google analytics for a framed page

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in ASP.NET C#, In my page I have  iframe with another page. I want to add a Goal in Google analytics when people press the Submit-linkbutton in the framed page.

While my url doesnt change when I press the submit button I have heard that you can use the following javascript to tell Analytics that you´re on the specified page:

> pageTracker._trackPageview('/booking.html');

So I have added the following line in the page_load function:

> SubmitButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "pageTracker._trackPageview('/booking.html');");

And in Google analytics have I added the goal url:

> /booking.html

But nothing happends in the goal section when I press the submit button.

Im really not sure of what im doing so some help had been really appreciated.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Since iframes are treated as completely separate pages, I suspect you need to add the tracking code to the framed content as well.

You might also try calling a function in the parent page which triggers the page tracker:

```
SubmitButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "parent.TrackPageView(window.location.href)");
```